# Accessing one smart contract contained in another smart contract from javascript

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, testing

I'm cross-posting this from Stack Overflow, since there seems to be more activity here.

I am trying to develop a dApp with Truffle and want to test my smart contract. The contract contains a second contract within it, like so:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract SubContract {
    uint public foo;

    constructor() public {
        foo = 0;
    }
}

contract MainContract {
    SubContract public my_contract;

    constructor() public {
        my_contract = new SubContract();
    }
}
```

I then want to test this contract in Javascript like so:

```js
var MainContract = artifacts.require("./MainContract.sol");

contract("MainContract", function(accounts) {

  it("initializes SubContract contract", function() {
    return MainContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.my_contract;
    }).then(function(subContractInstance) {
       return subContractInstance.foo();
    }).then(function(foo) {
      assert.equal(foo.toNumber(), 0);
    });
  });
});
```

If I then try to run this test as is, it tells me it cannot access member function `foo()` of `undefined`. If I change it from `instance.my_contract` to `instance.my_contract()` in the test, it tells me there is no function `contract()`, even though other fields are accessed through getter methods. What am I missing here to be able to access the SubContract instance?

---EDIT---

Per the suggestions, here's what a working test looks like:

```
var MainContract = artifacts.require("MainContract");
var SubContract  = artifacts.require("SubContract");

contract("MainContract", async accounts => {
  it("initializes SubContract contract", async() => {
    let instance = await MainContract.deployed();
    let subContractAddress = await instance.my_contract();
    let subContractInstance = await SubContract.at(subContractAddress);
    let foo = await subContractInstance.foo();
    assert.equal(foo.toNumber(), 0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your declaration of the `contract` variable is wrong, `contract` is a reserved keyword in Solidity. Let's say you rename it to `SubContract public my_contract`.

Second, accessing the `my_contract` variable through the getter automatically created for it doesn't return a `SubContract` instance but the address of the contract. So you will need to do the necessary manipulations in your script to interact with the `SubContract` by fetching its address from the `MainContract` and creating the correct instance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I changed the variable name in the example. Could you give an example of how to fetch the address of the SubContract instance?

Comment: `instance.my_contract()`

Comment: That's what I tried - but I still got an error saying that no such function exists

Comment: Specifically: `TypeError: instance.my_contract() is not a function`

Comment: Should be something like `SubContract.at (instance.my_contract()).foo()`.

Comment: Interesting - thanks. Does `SubContract.at` return a promise?

Comment: Although - one issue with that is that there is no `var SubContract` in the Javascript test. It also fails if I try `MainContract.SubContract.at`.

Comment: You have to think a bit. Split your original code in two parts, and then you can write a `require` statement for `SubContract` and then use it. Don't forget to use `await` when calling a contract's function.

Comment: Yes, I realize now I needed to split the `artifacts.require` call into two calls, one for each contract. Also in my original code (not reproduced here) it turns out I'd forgotten to declare my_contract public.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `await` however - what would that look like in the test?

Comment: https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#using-async-await

Comment: That looks much cleaner than the constant chains of `.then(function(instance){})` calls. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like I'm close now, but it's still giving me an error. I've updated the question with the latest version of the test.

Comment: Never mind, it seems the error is coming from somewhere else in the project. The example above works.